# Can zabbix run without bugzilla? how important bugzilla for zabbix (zabbix server running Value NO)

Tags: zabbix, bugzilla

At dashboards, it shows zabbix server running Value NO. Can bugzilla give the effect for this problem? if not what are the other cause that can make this problem happen?

Zabbix running NO:

[image]

Comment: One could answer "Yes, Zabbix can run without bugzilla", but the question does not seem to make sense. Zabbix has no relation to bugzilla, is there a mistake in the question?